# Error: super(type, obj) obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Tags: python, keras

Kindly assist troubleshoot my code on classification using machine learning
model. It throws up below error. The main essence of the code is to train a
model using imdb data to classify correctly between positive reviews and
negative reviews.

```
File "/Users/darlingtonemeagi/Downloads/untitled14.py", line 49, in <module>
    model = models.Sequential()

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 87, in __init__
    super(Sequential, self).__init__(name=name)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 96, in __init__
    self._init_subclassed_network(**kwargs)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 300, in _init_subclassed_network
    self._base_init(name=name)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 110, in _base_init
    self.name = name

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 322, in __setattr__
    super(Network, self).__setattr__(name, value)

TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type"
```

I have looked at the code critical without being able to spot where the problem is coming from.

```
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras.datasets import imdb
import numpy as np

(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = imdb.load_data(num_words=10000)

#Vectorised the data using Hot-encode technology

def vectorise_sequence(sequences, dimension=10000):
    results = np.zeros((len(sequences), dimension)) #Create zeros matrix of shape len(sequences) and dimension
    for i, sequence in enumerate(sequences):
        results[i, sequence] = 1 # set specific indices of results[i] to 1
    return results

#Vectorise training and test data

x_train = vectorise_sequence(train_data)
x_test = vectorise_sequence(test_data)

#Also vectorising the labels which is also straight forward

y_train = np.asarray(train_labels).astype('float32')
y_test = np.asarray(test_labels).astype('float32')

#The inputs data are vectors while the output data is scalar (0 and 1)

#Set aside a validation set: Data the model has never seen before in other to monitor
#the accuracy of the model

x_val= x_train[:10000]
partial_x_train = x_train[10000:]

y_val = y_train[:10000]
partial_y_train = y_train[10000:]

#Building the Network Model

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', input_size=(10000,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

#Compiling the network

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

history = model.fit(partial_x_train, partial_y_train, epochs=20,\
                    batch_size=512, validation_data = (x_val,y_val))

history_dict = history.history
print(history_dict.keys())

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

loss_values = history_dict['loss']
val_loss_values = history_dict['val_loss']

epochs = range(1, 20)
plt.plot(epochs, loss_values, 'bo', label='Training Loss')
plt.plot (epochs, val_loss_values, 'b', label='Validation Loss')
plt.title('Training and Validation Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.Legend()
plt.show()
```

The expected output is a graphical representation of the Training loss and Validation loss.

Comment: Are you getting this error [after reloading modules](https://thomas-cokelaer.info/blog/2011/09/382/)? If so, you may have to be careful about the order in which you reload modules. To see if this guess is on the right track, you could try running your script from a fresh Python process (preferably from the command line so there is no GUI middle man involved). If the script works there then it is likely the problem has to do with reloading.

Comment: @Unutbu, Thank you. The code ran successfully on terminal. The only change I effected was the input_size to input_shape.